# How to compress a 16-by-10 numpy array/opencv image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, compression, jpeg

I need to compress many 16-by-10 numpy array/opencv images. A jpg will output a to big file cause its not efficient at low res images.

`len(cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])[1])`

Comment: assuming you don't mean the aspect ratio but literally 16 by 10 pixels, right? -- save as `.npy`? or as bitmap? -- how about putting all those "image" in a stack, and then saving that as `.npy`

Comment: thanks yes thats a way to do it, npy is better than jpg but it will give me only a size reduction of two times, but a jpg will give me a reduction of 15 times for bigger pictures so i hope there is a better way to do it. stacking is not an option cause i need to send them one by one over UDP socket with a max of 506 bytes  (latency is important)

Comment: what is that, color or grayscale, 8-bit? you're talking about 160/480 bytes each, uncompressed. just send plain and raw. you need no headers at all, apart from your own protocol stuff. -- if you're satisfied with lossless, just gzip it or whatever. if you _need_ to lossy, you could *reinvent* JPEG, i.e. convert to YUV, do the DCT on your data, quantize and whatnot, and the other side has to assume a few things so you don't have to send the information that's usually in JPEG headers, for every picture.